# Stacking floated Divs

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, css-float

I have a group of rectangular Divs, all of class 'Bar', these are all floated far right inside the container which also contains a similar set-up floated left inside it.
In Google Chrome this works fine and the bars are stacked on top of each other with spacing of a 
 between them. However in IE the bars are shown below the floated left content and are not stacked on top of each other.

Please say if more info is needed I tried to include only most important so the post isnt too long.

Thanks in advance

```
.Bar {
    border-color: #666;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;    
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:6px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin:6px 0 0 0;
    float:right;
    line-height:25px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: If possible post the html and css in http://jsfiddle.net/ and provide link

Comment: Here is the code, Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/BradStevo/ubnjc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `bdInnerBar` class's `float:right` fixes situation on my side, even more the right bars get blue color.

Sorry, I can't get the reason for this, if possible please clean-up the html and css to have only relevant parts in them, if you want to get more general answer.